Out of memory while running MIP model in Python with Gurobi package
I am solving a MIP model in Python with the Gurobi package. My mine CPU is as follows:
CPU model: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1145G7 @ 2.60GHz, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2|AVX512]
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 1 thread.
I got an error of out of memory after a long time. Then, I changed the machine and I am using a computer with following characteristics:
CPU model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8488C, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2|AVX512]
Thread count: 16 physical cores, 32 logical processors, using up to 32 threads.
I also changed some parameters in the code. I Set parameter NodefileStart to value 0, parameter PreSparsify to value 1, Threads to value 32, and Method to value 1. But It seems it takes too long to solve the model. After 5 hours, it did not even start to show the optimality gap. Note that, I am optimizing a large-scale model with 341696 rows, 531828 columns, and 8060314 nonzeros.
The model has 66392 general constraints, and in terms of Variable types, there are 525808 continuous, 6020 integers (6020 binary).
Optimize a model with 341696 rows, 531828 columns and 8060314 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x03a35757
Model has 66392 general constraints
Variable types: 525808 continuous, 6020 integer (6020 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+03]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 3e+01]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+02]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+03]
Presolve removed 200078 rows and 376353 columns (presolve time = 5s) ...
Presolve removed 402656 rows and 557750 columns (presolve time = 10s) ...
Presolve removed 142968 rows and 340820 columns
Presolve time: 10.65s
Presolved: 198728 rows, 191008 columns, 1282723 nonzeros
Variable types: 144810 continuous, 46198 integer (46198 binary)

Root simplex log...

Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0      handle free variables                         15s
   20513   -2.1293648e+02   9.651873e+03   0.000000e+00     15s
   76702    2.8460022e+04   1.859709e+05   0.000000e+00     20s
   93074    4.1566715e+04   1.624518e+05   0.000000e+00     25s
  149842    9.3549408e+04   1.472253e+04   0.000000e+00     30s
  189058    1.0409371e+05   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00     32s

Root relaxation: objective 1.040937e+05, 189058 iterations, 17.36 seconds (14.57 work units)
Total elapsed time = 32.14s (DegenMoves)

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0 104093.712    0  862          - 104093.712      -     -   33s
     0     0 105046.082    0 1442          - 105046.082      -     -   42s
     0     0 105046.082    0 1472          - 105046.082      -     -   44s
     0     0 105390.805    0 1214          - 105390.805      -     -   50s
     0     0 105395.767    0 1339          - 105395.767      -     -   52s
     0     0 105395.767    0 1339          - 105395.767      -     -   53s
     0     0 105395.774    0 1340          - 105395.774      -     -   53s
     0     0 105395.774    0 1340          - 105395.774      -     -   53s
     0     0 105866.005    0  904          - 105866.005      -     -   58s
     0     0 105866.005    0  903          - 105866.005      -     -   58s
     0     0 105866.406    0  888          - 105866.406      -     -   62s
     0     0 105866.406    0  893          - 105866.406      -     -   62s
     0     0 105889.713    0  799          - 105889.713      -     -   66s
     0     0 105889.992    0  794          - 105889.992      -     -   69s
     0     0 105889.997    0  807          - 105889.997      -     -   69s
     0     0 105899.597    0  780          - 105899.597      -     -   71s
     0     0 105899.740    0  785          - 105899.740      -     -   75s
     0     0 105901.403    0  796          - 105901.403      -     -   77s
     0     0 105901.403    0  795          - 105901.403      -     -   79s
     0     0 105901.679    0  754          - 105901.679      -     -   81s
     0     0 105901.682    0  760          - 105901.682      -     -   83s
     0     0 105901.682    0  762          - 105901.682      -     -   84s
     0     0 105901.682    0  761          - 105901.682      -     -   87s
     0     0 105901.682    0  763          - 105901.682      -     -   88s
     0     0 105901.682    0  358          - 105901.682      -     -   95s
     0     2 105901.682    0  348          - 105901.682      -     -  120s
    27    32 105918.257    4  362          - 105901.682      -   629  125s
    95   128 105917.913    7  399          - 105901.682      -   282  130s
   223   256 105917.913    9  397          - 105901.682      -   152  135s
   351   384 105918.235   11  396          - 105901.682      -   115  141s
   415   448 105918.235   13  395          - 105901.682      -   110  145s
   517   550 105918.235   16  392          - 105901.682      -   105  152s
   549   608 105927.406   16  393          - 105901.682      -   111  156s
   607   670 105918.959   17  404          - 105901.682      -   122  161s
   669   729 105935.143   19  406          - 105901.682      -   134  165s
   728   804 105935.799   19  405          - 105901.682      -   141  170s
   803   876 105953.342   20  405          - 105901.682      -   154  176s
   875   962 105949.100   21  403          - 105901.682      -   170  182s
   961  1050 105959.790   23  405          - 105901.682      -   177  188s
  1049  1206 105967.583   25  387          - 105901.682      -   183  196s
  1205  1533 105982.051   28  396          - 105901.682      -   202  203s
  1532  1860 106012.671   36  386          - 105901.682      -   206  209s
  1859  2159 106036.111   43  412          - 105901.682      -   204  216s
  2158  2461 106058.068   46  409          - 105901.682      -   207  222s
Created node file directory './grbnodes3'
  2462  2756 106079.888   51  416          - 105901.682      -   207  230s
  2760  3089 106115.099   54  439          - 105901.682      -   211  238s
  3099  3403 106142.890   66  376          - 105901.682      -   217  246s
  3413  3757 106167.369   74  395          - 105901.682      -   212  254s
  3767  4177 106174.232   81  393          - 105901.682      -   211  261s
  4190  4559 106191.161   95  466          - 105901.682      -   209  269s
  4578  4974 106196.510  101  450          - 105901.682      -   212  277s
  4995  5437 106206.430  107  448          - 105901.682      -   211  285s
  5463  5892 106239.954  116  511          - 105901.682      -   206  293s
  5923  6343 106253.410  131  445          - 105901.682      -   204  302s
  6375  6855 106259.893  146  496          - 105901.682      -   200  310s
  6890  7249 106266.247  155  488          - 105901.682      -   197  321s
  7287  7783 106270.041  167  497          - 105901.682      -   197  330s
  7830  8265 106284.954  179  487          - 105901.682      -   194  340s
  8383  8770 106391.595  192  487          - 105901.682      -   198  351s
  8900  9280 106417.717  202  499          - 105901.682      -   201  362s
  9445  9841 106441.564  209  533          - 105901.682      -   202  375s
 10024 10444 106453.098  228  478          - 105901.682      -   206  386s
 10661 10969 infeasible  242               - 105901.682      -   206  400s
 11236 11547 106691.031  253  517          - 105901.682      -   208  414s
 11878 12285 106718.854  280  507          - 105901.682      -   208  430s
 12689 12770 106758.127  297  501          - 105901.682      -   208  445s
 13333 13251 106946.726  313  593          - 105901.682      -   215  460s
 13924 13895 infeasible  318               - 105901.682      -   225  475s
 14662 13896 106159.953   50 22130          - 105901.682      -   229  926s
 14664 13897 106061.709   62  862          - 105901.682      -   229  966s
 14665 13898 105964.620   26 1048          - 105901.682      -   229  978s
 14666 13899 106271.931  200  905          - 105901.682      -   229  988s
 14667 13899 105927.337   22  915          - 105901.682      -   229  990s
 14668 13900 105943.032   20  919          - 105901.682      -   229 1003s
 14669 13901 106619.953  327  827          - 105904.008      -   229 1009s
 14670 13901 106115.832   98  828          - 105904.008      -   229 1022s
 14671 13902 106053.054   58  777          - 105905.429      -   229 1028s
 14672 13903 106619.953  328  794          - 105905.441      -   229 1031s
 14673 13903 106308.614  163  783          - 105905.441      -   229 1047s
 14674 13904 105926.400   14  717          - 105905.636      -   229 1051s
 14676 13905 105963.285   25  707          - 105905.988      -   229 1071s
 14677 13906 105976.230   21  705          - 105907.552      -   229 1075s
 14678 13907 105916.843   19  729          - 105908.177      -   229 1083s
 14680 13908 105955.791   24  730          - 105908.222      -   229 1085s
 14681 13909 105953.333   20  729          - 105908.222      -   229 1105s
 14682 13909 105954.634   19  719          - 105909.139      -   229 1111s
 14683 13910 105966.741   23  709          - 105909.289      -   229 1117s
 14684 13911 105945.036   20  704          - 105909.296      -   229 1138s
 14685 13911 106584.173  165  718          - 105910.146      -   229 1142s
 14686 13912 105952.238   18  713          - 105910.151      -   229 1167s
 14687 13913 106165.760  192  700          - 105910.778      -   229 1170s
 14688 13913 105926.618   12  697          - 105910.787      -   229 1187s
 14690 13915 106395.066  188  713          - 105911.109      -   229 1190s
 14691 13915 105992.824   37  721          - 105911.112      -   229 1200s
 14694 13917 105971.649   26  735          - 105911.293      -   228 1214s
 14695 13918 106165.760  192  740          - 105911.357      -   228 1217s
 14697 13919 105918.238    6  745          - 105911.371      -   228 1228s
 14698 13920 105939.774   22  722          - 105911.372      -   228 1231s
 14699 13921 106308.872   84  719          - 105911.372      -   228 1241s
 14700 13921 105928.656   19  723          - 105911.539      -   228 1245s
 14701 13922 106059.663   38  741          - 105911.547      -   228 1254s
 14702 13923 105933.505   18  730          - 105911.553      -   228 1255s
 14707 13927 105911.553   14  862          - 105911.553      -   245 1293s
 14708 13928 105936.395   17 1012          - 105911.553      -   245 1303s
 14709 13929 105926.642   14  907          - 105911.650      -   245 1311s
 14713 13931 105911.650   15  931          - 105911.650      -   245 1328s
 14714 13932 106322.584  190  881          - 105911.658      -   245 1334s
 14715 13933 105918.266   11  877          - 105911.658      -   245 1348s
 14716 13933 105942.471   19  809          - 105911.774      -   245 1354s
 14717 13934 105974.374   27  816          - 105911.793      -   245 1355s
 14718 13935 105932.702   13  810          - 105911.797      -   245 1369s
 14719 13935 105965.748   14  866          - 105911.907      -   245 1373s
 14720 13936 106253.601  153  818          - 105911.911      -   245 1388s
 14721 13937 105925.718    9  819          - 105912.055      -   245 1394s
 14722 13937 105946.162   20  786          - 105912.628      -   245 1398s
 14723 13938 106234.364  161  792          - 105912.699      -   245 1400s
 14724 13939 105990.734   20  789          - 105912.707      -   245 1417s
 14725 13939 105961.063   23  775          - 105913.140      -   245 1421s
 14726 13940 105929.276   14  782          - 105913.141      -   245 1438s
 14727 13941 106283.238  187  767          - 105913.151      -   245 1442s
 14728 13941 106233.209  161  791          - 105913.347      -   245 1447s
 14731 13943 105976.713   23  808          - 105913.484      -   245 1467s
 14732 13944 105920.485   13  809          - 105913.548      -   244 1470s
 14733 13945 109012.416  330  799          - 105913.548      -   244 1490s
 14734 13945 106225.973  163  757          - 105913.582      -   244 1498s
 14735 13946 105993.667   36  777          - 105913.595      -   244 1503s
 14737 13947 106322.874  191  757          - 105913.606      -   244 1518s
 14738 13948 106414.377  193  760          - 105913.646      -   244 1521s
 14740 13949 106268.904  193  763          - 105913.678      -   244 1532s
 14741 13950 106165.760  192  759          - 105914.039      -   244 1535s
 14742 13951 106199.860  211  752          - 105914.042      -   244 1545s
 14744 13952 106057.949   63  742          - 105914.146      -   244 1558s
 14745 13953 105939.774   22  748          - 105914.172      -   244 1561s
 14746 13953 105969.820   22  745          - 105914.172      -   244 1571s
 14748 13955 105969.282   24  740          - 105914.172      -   244 1584s
 14749 13955 106247.192   93  745          - 105914.181      -   244 1588s
 14750 13956 105926.674    8  746          - 105914.181      -   244 1595s
 14751 13957 105946.644   20  730          - 105914.181      -   244 1613s
 14752 13957 106177.585   63  730          - 105914.181      -   244 1630s
 14753 13958 105918.324   12  730          - 105914.181      -   244 1650s
 14754 13962 105930.289   21  709          - 105914.181      -   281 1688s
 14756 13965 105965.785   22  672          - 105914.181      -   281 1699s
 14760 13972 105983.377   23  689          - 105914.181      -   282 1711s
 14768 13985 106012.179   24  690          - 105914.181      -   282 1728s
 14784 14012 106027.180   25  688          - 105914.181      -   283 1746s
 14848 14054 106035.261   26  691          - 105914.181      -   286 1752s
 14880 14076 106035.135   27  768          - 105914.181      -   286 1755s
 14944 14121 106035.535   28  761          - 105914.181      -   286 1760s
 15013 14169 106035.245   29  766          - 105914.181      -   285 1765s
 15136 14244 106037.484   31  775          - 105914.181      -   284 1772s
 15168 14265 106042.743   32  761          - 105914.181      -   284 1776s
 15234 14303 106051.930   33  774          - 105914.181      -   285 1859s
 15269 14326 106044.815   33  765          - 105914.181      -   285 1862s
 15306 14357 106047.251   34  781          - 105914.181      -   286 1867s
 15353 14399 106054.472   34  765          - 105914.181      -   287 1871s
 15464 14468 106049.421   36  775          - 105914.181      -   289 1877s
 15517 14503 106052.449   37  777          - 105914.181      -   290 1881s
 15570 14541 106123.806   38  776          - 105914.181      -   290 1885s
 15626 14572 106059.093   39  778          - 105914.181      -   291 1890s
 15746 14649 106061.602   41  756          - 105914.181      -   293 1899s
 15800 14679 106068.560   42  754          - 105914.181      -   294 1904s
 15850 14716 106074.381   43  753          - 105914.181      -   294 1909s
 15907 14752 106074.469   44  737          - 105914.181      -   295 1915s
 15965 14792 106077.390   45  743          - 105914.181      -   297 1921s
 16024 14828 106076.425   46  732          - 105914.181      -   298 1927s
 16080 14878 106083.415   47  780          - 105914.181      -   300 1934s
 16152 14908 106082.668   48  680          - 105914.181      -   302 1941s
 16208 14961 106084.745   49  790          - 105914.181      -   304 1947s
 16280 15035 106092.303   50  783          - 105914.181      -   306 1954s
 16384 15091 106089.390   52  738          - 105914.181      -   308 1962s
 16480 15120 106094.087   53  739          - 105914.181      -   309 1971s
 16544 15170 106109.315   54  739          - 105914.181      -   311 1978s
 16622 15233 106105.686   56  726          - 105914.181      -   312 1985s
 16722 15392 106115.172   58  747          - 105914.181      -   314 1991s
 16919 15528 106136.514   61  753          - 105914.181      -   319 1998s
 17132 15681 106143.011   65  723          - 105914.181      -   321 2005s
 17365 15651 106151.633   70  739          - 105914.181      -   325 2014s
 17456 15765 106160.805   71  724          - 105914.181      -   327 2026s
 17652 15858 106161.392   74  727          - 105914.181      -   336 2037s
 17849 16037 106171.431   79  720          - 105914.181      -   343 2045s
 18102 16048 106182.082   85  661          - 105914.181      -   348 2056s
 18216 16269 106183.147   87  704          - 105914.181      -   350 2064s
 18512 16490 106188.911   93  651          - 105914.181      -   355 2073s
 18833 16500 106195.549   99  690          - 105914.181      -   360 2083s
 18976 16768 106211.166  101  626          - 105914.181      -   361 2093s
 19317 17024 106199.777  108  692          - 105914.181      -   365 2102s
 19695 17037 106203.277  114  677          - 105914.181      -   369 2113s
 19858 17386 106235.215  117  723          - 105914.181      -   372 2124s
 20287 17618 106208.996  123  661          - 105914.181      -   374 2134s
 20694 17681 106213.135  133  647          - 105914.181      -   377 2146s
 20921 18032 106219.114  137  650          - 105914.181      -   379 2157s
 21393 18247 106232.149  147  642          - 105914.181      -   381 2171s
 21803 18296 106230.550  156  643          - 105914.181      -   382 2190s
 22047 18589 106233.136  159  633          - 105914.181      -   382 2203s
 22461 18895 106236.053  167  623          - 105914.181      -   385 2216s
 22960 19060 106243.917  174  611          - 105914.181      -   386 2233s
 23355 19501 106238.579  181  616          - 105914.181      -   388 2247s
 23966 19802 106240.526  193  539          - 105914.181      -   390 2262s
 24523 20128 106248.670  201  548          - 105914.181      -   391 2277s
 25096 20570 106252.124  210  524          - 105914.181      -   394 2292s
 25788 20919 106253.827  221  494          - 105914.181      -   395 2307s
 26399 21400 106260.590  233  433          - 105914.181      -   397 2323s
 27158 21749 106260.622  238  429          - 105914.181      -   397 2339s
 27382 21674 106179.280   78  719          - 105914.181      -   399 2340s
 27880 21965 106263.250  252  382          - 105914.181      -   400 2358s
 28422 22319 106269.341  261  471          - 105914.181      -   404 2378s
 29078 22833 106269.900  272  466          - 105914.181      -   406 2394s
 29668 22636 106516.776  273  378          - 105914.181      -   409 2395s
 29864 22699 106282.806  283  388          - 105914.181      -   410 2704s
 30031 25101 106270.452  285  402          - 105914.181      -   410 2770s
 32687 24867 106280.601  326  371          - 105914.181      -   414 2791s
 33366 25526 106279.479  336  359          - 105914.181      -   415 2819s
 34336 26012 106273.188  352  291          - 105914.181      -   418 2860s
 35375 26211 106275.033  373  273          - 105914.181      -   420 2885s
 36009 26837 106279.878  378  270          - 105914.181      -   426 2917s
 36940 27455 106279.878  397  246          - 105914.181      -   429 2946s
 37994 27977 106283.362  423  222          - 105914.181      -   430 2973s
 38968 28722 106284.263  445  210          - 105914.181      -   433 2998s
 40116 29485 106333.149  462  304          - 105914.181      -   435 3023s
 41348 30299 106357.949  473  263          - 105914.181      -   436 3055s
 42669 30565 infeasible  482               - 105914.181      -   436 3101s
 43582 30547 infeasible  482               - 105914.181      -   441 3151s
 44064 31456 105940.254   36  758          - 105914.181      -   444 3194s
 45463 32134 106135.585   48  762          - 105914.181      -   448 3235s
 46818 32154 106193.519   74  737          - 105914.181      -   454 3284s
 47539 33134 106228.646   84  666          - 105914.181      -   457 3319s
 49029 33726 106290.726  105  654          - 105914.181      -   463 3355s
 50351 34531 106363.132  124  629          - 105914.181      -   466 3420s
 51821 35332 106456.982  137  717          - 105914.181      -   469 3465s
 53486 36334 106498.326  148  753          - 105914.181      -   473 3531s
 55465 37264 106549.589  191  697          - 105914.181      -   475 3603s
 57468 38291 106577.976  222  543          - 105914.181      -   477 3674s
 59441 38292 105928.360   30 21800          - 105914.181      -   481 8295s
 59443 38293 105925.430   32  862          - 105914.181      -   481 8374s
 59444 38294 106902.223  175 1001          - 105914.181      -   481 8403s
 59445 38295 106212.910  120  961          - 105915.566      -   481 8422s
 59447 38296 106099.440   53  907          - 105917.287      -   481 8426s
 59449 38297 105967.709   39  933          - 105917.423      -   481 8432s
 59450 38298 106299.014  790  919          - 105917.447      -   481 8446s
 59451 38299 107151.621  114  925          - 105917.447      -   481 8492s
 59452 38299 105990.272   54  825          - 105917.597      -   481 8497s
 59453 38300 105926.024   36  810          - 105917.597      -   481 8549s
 59454 38301 106189.456  113  842          - 105917.631      -   481 8554s
 59455 38301 105994.321   62  833          - 105917.699      -   481 8556s
 59457 38303 106293.271   70  860          - 105917.710      -   481 8633s
 59458 38303 105972.492   52  782          - 105917.773      -   481 8640s
 59459 38304 105945.004   40  808          - 105917.779      -   481 8717s
 59460 38305 105935.877   48  818          - 105917.883      -   481 8723s
 59461 38305 106617.843  236  811          - 105918.121      -   481 8730s
 59462 38306 106013.349   48  821          - 105918.145      -   481 8736s
 59464 38307 106526.057  100  806          - 105918.334      -   481 8815s
 59465 38308 106415.969   79  749          - 105919.091      -   481 8820s
 59467 38309 105947.095   39  748          - 105919.120      -   481 8877s
 59468 38310 106214.891   67  770          - 105919.353      -   481 8881s
 59471 38312 105964.644   51  781          - 105919.492      -   481 8919s
 59472 38313 105954.220   62  778          - 105919.492      -   481 8924s
 59473 38313 106009.944   60  763          - 105919.492      -   481 8958s
 59474 38314 105932.821   38  780          - 105919.498      -   481 8962s
 59475 38315 106298.689  769  775          - 105919.498      -   481 8997s
 59476 38315 105927.140   27  763          - 105919.505      -   481 9000s
 59477 38316 105937.216   36  766          - 105919.505      -   481 9033s
 59478 38317 106805.953   98  751          - 105919.507      -   481 9038s


Hi, may I kindly ask you to provide a full model output log, it would give much more information about the solution progress. Information that you've provided is not enough, because solving MIP is happening in several steps: 1) solving model with relaxed constraints and assuming all variables are continuos; 2) solving MIP part with branch and bound. And in most cases if you have 6k binary variables you will never reach a true optimal solution. Usually you set model gap parameter to 1% and this helps the model to stop earlier on near-optimal solution.

... so information that the model finished part 1 and started part 2, branch and bound, and also that solver reached specific MIP gap should be available form the model output logs.

Regarding your hardware specification, my recommendations would be to rent Gurobi Cloud instance, they are better optimized for solving model using all available threads.

@JohnnyCheesecutter Thank you for your reply. Let me share with you a part of the log.

I would recommend to share at least last 20-30 rows of the model logs. Or if possible full logs for the first 20-30 minutes of training.

I appreciate your time. I updated my question on the above. Please look at it. -@JohnnyCheesecutter

also regarding model parallelization. Do you see in logs that model is using all threads? Smth like this Thread count: 8 physical cores, 16 logical processors, using up to 4 threads

Here is what you want:
Gurobi Optimizer version 11.0.1 build v11.0.1rc0 (win64 - Windows Server 2022.0 (20348.2))
CPU model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8488C, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2|AVX512]
Thread count: 16 physical cores, 32 logical processors, using up to 32 threads
Academic license 2511048 - for non-commercial use only - registered to
Optimize a model with 341696 rows, 531828 columns and 8060314 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x03a35757
Model has 66392 general constraints
Variable types: 525808 continuous, 6020 integer (6020 binary)`

Cool. I think that 32 cores is quite a decent amount for many complex tasks. And Gurobi is claiming that it use all of them thus multiprocessing is configured correctly. So the problem is definitely not in lack of computing power.

This is not normal: you are correctly using node files to handle the large number of MIP nodes, yet you are still running out of memory during node solves. I suggest you open a Gurobi support ticket at support.gurobi.com to investigate further.

The solving continues after 8 hours without starting to show any gap. I mean, in the new machine, the out-of-memory error has been solved, but it is taking too long to solve.-@GregGlockner

Sry, I'll write a post instead of a comment, because this allows to add pictures and point out several things that you should check when running LP models.
Problem number 1.
You said that the model has 6k binary variables which is a reasonable number, but after relaxation stage Gurobi concluded that actual number of binary variables is 46k. This means that to implement some of the constraints you need to introduce additional binary variables. From my experience 46k is too many and basically this is why your model remains unsolvable.

Simplifying a lot 'branch-and-bound' is a combinatorial search of good integers that don't violate your constraints. And obviously combinatorial search for 46k binary variables (which of them should be 0 and which 1) is very hard task.
Problem number 2:
Incumbent and Gap are Nones during branch and bound. This means that the model can't find ANY feasible solutions for the problem (even single very non-optimal solution wasn't found). Usually you would expect to find first feasible solution very soon, at least in first 5-10 minutes of branch and bound (picture shows the beginning of branch-and-bound).

no feasible solutions found after 2.5 hours (9k seconds) of 'branch-and-bound'

My conculsions:
You've encounter a very hard problem to tackle.

I would recommend to review the task and to decide: do you need any feasible solution or solution close to optimal? For example, if your task is related to scheduling jobs done by employees you most probably will be fine with any solution and don't need the closest to optimal;
Break your task in parts. For example if you do a monthly planning break tasks in 4 weeks: do a week by week planning;
Review constraints that require additional binary variables. Remove them from the model or think how to replace them with continuous constraints; Read science articles about similar problems/tasks and how to tackle them efficiently;
Think if you can find and provide to Gurobi any feasible solution yourself using greedy search or smart combinatorial search. If you have any feasible solution that you can pass as a hint to the Gurobi this will significantly speed up branch-and-bound optimization.


Thank you for your explanation. Do you still recommend using the Gurobi cloud instance?

In your case I don't think that adding more threads/ switching to the cloud will help Gurobi to solve the problem. Usually if Gurobi can't find at least one feasible solution after reasonable amount of time I personally would prefer to revise the model specification (remove constraints, break model in parts and etc). Tuning threads is reasonable if you can see any gap with optimal solution (for example gap of 50%) and you would like to speed up the convergence to 1% gap.

But again, if you task is to find at least one feasible solution the tuning strategy might be different.

Also you can try to play with settings that triggers Gurobi to find at least one feasible solution, because this is current bottleneck in solving your model:
mipfocus = 1
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/mipfocus.html
But I doubt that this will somehow simplify your situation.

Thank you @JohnnyCheesecutter I see what you mean. I have some nonlinear constraints via the max function. Maybe I should revise them.

Try removing the objective function, i.e. set it to 0, then solving to try and find a feasible solution.  This could be used as MIP start for a solve with the objective function restored.  Also try experimenting with the NoRelHeurTime parameter.  Set it to a large value and see how long it takes to reach Phase 2 (Phase 1 is looking for a feasible solution).

Fortunately, I could pass phase 1 by adjusting some parameters and constraints of the model. As a quick question, I just want to ask you to make sure my MIP start solution code is correct. Please see the following: -@JohnnyCheesecutter

for (t,j,beta) in product(range(p), range(m), range(b):
s[t,j,beta].start = 0  model.update()
# # Optimize the model
model.optimize() @JohnnyCheesecutter

Hello Vida, great that you've solved the problem. As for the start solution, basically if all zeros is a valid starting solution Gurobi will be able to find it by itself (during heuristic search). Also if the passed solution is valid you'll this information in logs (it will basically check that passed values doesn't violate anything).

Hello again @JohnnyCheesecutter, I have "Warning: Completing partial solution with 1806 unfixed non-continuous variables out of 1806 User MIP start did not produce a new incumbent solution" in the log.

Hi, as it saying you either didn't properly passed the solution to the Gurobi API or didn't cover all existing variables in the model. Check that you are following this guide: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043834831-How-do-I-use-MIP-starts And again, if your freasible solution is simply all zeros you don't need to pass it explicitly.

@JohnnyCheesecutter I just want to add a comment. Based on what I have read the warning says the initial solution is infeasible. Anyway, thank you for your replies throughout this post. I passed this issue, but I have another one. You can see the link  https://stackoverflow.com/q/78452668/22362357 for my question if you are interested.
