Taking too long from 0.08% Gap to 0% while solving a MIP in Python with Gurobi package
I am solving a MIP problem in Python. The solving process with branch and bound proceeds very fast at the beginning, but when the optimality gap reaches 0.08% the opposite happens. I mean, from 0.08% to 0.07%, it takes too long, and so forth.
How could I handle this and get the optimal solution with 0 gap faster? You can have a look at a part of the log in the following.
Set parameter Presolve to value 2
Number of delta variables: 656
Number of theta variables: 656
Number of alfa variables: 1558
Number of q variables: 656
Set parameter MIPFocus to value 3
Set parameter CliqueCuts to value 2
Set parameter Cuts to value 3
Gurobi Optimizer version 11.0.1 build v11.0.1rc0 (win64 - Windows 10.0 (19045.2))

CPU model: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1145G7 @ 2.60GHz, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2|AVX512]
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads

Optimize a model with 102276 rows, 254294 columns and 599789 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0xafd3d5bd
Variable types: 250768 continuous, 3526 integer (3526 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+03]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 3e+01]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+03]
Found heuristic solution: objective 47194.000000
Presolve removed 81042 rows and 228106 columns
Presolve time: 0.17s
Presolved: 21234 rows, 26188 columns, 205061 nonzeros
Variable types: 24182 continuous, 2006 integer (2006 binary)
Root relaxation presolve removed 1048 rows and 1044 columns
Root relaxation presolved: 14910 rows, 21381 columns, 119432 nonzeros

Deterministic concurrent LP optimizer: primal and dual simplex
Showing primal log only...

Concurrent spin time: 0.00s

Solved with primal simplex
Extra simplex iterations after uncrush: 920

Root relaxation: objective 4.519969e+04, 10162 iterations, 0.36 seconds (0.18 work units)

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0 45199.6932    0  377 47194.0000 45199.6932  4.23%     -    2s
H    0     0                    46912.037037 46172.7708  1.58%     -    3s
     0     0 46172.7708    0  172 46912.0370 46172.7708  1.58%     -    4s
     0     0 46186.7711    0  232 46912.0370 46186.7711  1.55%     -    7s
H    0     0                    46906.666667 46191.7133  1.52%     -    7s
     0     0 46191.7133    0  235 46906.6667 46191.7133  1.52%     -    7s
     0     0 46192.6046    0  242 46906.6667 46192.6046  1.52%     -    7s
     0     0 46192.7941    0  237 46906.6667 46192.7941  1.52%     -    8s
     0     0 46198.3590    0  229 46906.6667 46198.3590  1.51%     -    9s
     0     0 46201.3162    0  262 46906.6667 46201.3162  1.50%     -   10s
     0     0 46201.3162    0  277 46906.6667 46201.3162  1.50%     -   10s
     0     0 46201.3162    0  275 46906.6667 46201.3162  1.50%     -   10s
     0     0 46203.3221    0  296 46906.6667 46203.3221  1.50%     -   13s
     0     0 46204.8289    0  309 46906.6667 46204.8289  1.50%     -   13s
     0     0 46204.8289    0  315 46906.6667 46204.8289  1.50%     -   14s
     0     0 46204.8289    0  314 46906.6667 46204.8289  1.50%     -   14s
     0     0 46204.8985    0  316 46906.6667 46204.8985  1.50%     -   15s
     0     0 46206.3098    0  327 46906.6667 46206.3098  1.49%     -   16s
     0     0 46206.3098    0  295 46906.6667 46206.3098  1.49%     -   17s
     0     0 46207.3030    0  313 46906.6667 46207.3030  1.49%     -   18s
H    0     0                    46836.166667 46207.3030  1.34%     -   19s
H    0     0                    46836.133333 46207.3030  1.34%     -   19s
     0     0 46207.3030    0  326 46836.1333 46207.3030  1.34%     -   20s
     0     0 46210.1540    0  326 46836.1333 46210.1540  1.34%     -   24s
H    0     0                    46831.222222 46210.1540  1.33%     -   26s
H    0     0                    46402.530748 46210.1540  0.41%     -   32s
     0     2 46210.1540    0  301 46402.5307 46210.1540  0.41%     -   33s
     7    12 46223.0835    3  305 46402.5307 46211.5317  0.41%   755   35s
H   27    37                    46400.530748 46218.4866  0.39%   778   40s
H   70    82                    46399.864082 46223.0806  0.38%   636   45s
   102   125 46264.3876    8  310 46399.8641 46225.6665  0.38%   652   52s
H  105   125                    46379.137805 46225.6665  0.33%   642   52s
H  109   125                    46377.443784 46225.7893  0.33%   643   52s
   124   165 46230.7686    7  340 46377.4438 46226.6118  0.33%   633   55s
   219   279 46260.1671    8  277 46377.4438 46228.4318  0.32%   485   61s
H  292   341                    46337.832202 46229.9055  0.23%   447   66s
   365   453 46235.9903    9  319 46337.8322 46231.2884  0.23%   434   70s
H  494   521                    46337.171768 46232.4550  0.23%   409   74s
   566   616 46235.3091    5  325 46337.1718 46233.1271  0.22%   410   77s
   674   690 46244.4814    9  308 46337.1718 46234.2224  0.22%   403   81s
   758   762     cutoff    8      46337.1718 46235.8784  0.22%   411   87s
H  779   745                    46328.408597 46235.8784  0.20%   411   87s
H  819   744                    46327.554994 46235.9614  0.20%   417   87s
   850   831 46238.2180   10  325 46327.5550 46237.1706  0.20%   420   92s
H  982   863                    46327.210392 46238.5472  0.19%   420  100s
H  996   861                    46326.032650 46238.7178  0.19%   419  100s
H 1019   859                    46325.884923 46238.7481  0.19%   417  100s
  1025   948 46241.0344   11  302 46325.8849 46239.3971  0.19%   418  106s
  1164  1104     cutoff   12      46325.8849 46241.6109  0.18%   432  113s
H 1371  1104                    46325.859893 46243.2630  0.18%   429  114s
  1372  1105 46257.7263   14  922 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   429  119s
  1374  1106 46252.0188   10  380 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   428  121s
  1375  1107 46270.1376   22  199 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   428  125s
H 1375  1051                    46325.859881 46243.2630  0.18%   428  125s
  1382  1056 46269.5730   12  370 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   426  131s
H 1382  1003                    46325.859875 46243.2630  0.18%   426  136s
  1383  1003 46245.7432   18  371 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   425  142s
  1388  1007 46258.6400   19  387 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   424  148s
  1389  1007 46252.8441   16  391 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   423  157s
  1395  1011 46256.0137   22  469 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   422  164s
  1396  1012 46265.0506   13  446 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   421  175s
  1405  1018 46264.4825   12  507 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   419  183s
  1406  1019 46260.1460   10  468 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   418  195s
  1413  1023 46259.4821   21  508 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   416  204s
  1414  1024 46262.8705   22  471 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   416  217s
  1420  1028 46260.6866   15  526 46325.8599 46243.2630  0.18%   414  224s
  1421  1029 46259.5025   28  439 46325.8599 46245.6072  0.17%   414  235s
  1427  1033 46265.3972   20  550 46325.8599 46248.2696  0.17%   412  244s
  1428  1033 46258.4860   22  524 46325.8599 46249.6196  0.16%   412  257s
  1432  1036 46257.4378   19  584 46325.8599 46249.7852  0.16%   411  264s
  1433  1037 46252.1537   15  528 46325.8599 46252.1537  0.16%   410  274s
H 1433   984                    46325.859771 46252.1537  0.16%   410  275s
  1440   988 46255.2877   17  606 46325.8598 46252.5803  0.16%   408  282s
  1441   989 46258.9775   15  514 46325.8598 46254.3249  0.15%   408  292s
  1446   992 46259.2605   13  578 46325.8598 46254.6226  0.15%   407  299s
  1447   993 46261.1810   16  547 46325.8598 46255.6288  0.15%   407  309s
  1449   994 46256.0043   19  582 46325.8598 46255.6288  0.15%   406  310s
  1452   996 46267.1060   13  517 46325.8598 46255.6288  0.15%   405  324s
  1453   997 46255.6288   20  541 46325.8598 46255.6288  0.15%   405  325s
  1456   999 46255.6288   16  598 46325.8598 46255.6288  0.15%   404  330s
  1457  1000 46261.4153   25  554 46325.8598 46256.0901  0.15%   404  340s
  1461  1002 46256.1570   14  591 46325.8598 46256.1570  0.15%   403  346s
  1462  1003 46256.4694   13  532 46325.8598 46256.4694  0.15%   402  352s
  1465  1005 46256.4694   12  574 46325.8598 46256.4694  0.15%   402  355s
  1466  1006 46256.6433   19  563 46325.8598 46256.6433  0.15%   401  362s
  1470  1008 46256.6854   13  604 46325.8598 46256.6854  0.15%   400  367s
H 1470   956                    46325.859751 46258.9142  0.14%   400  371s
  1472   958 46259.1078   14  512 46325.8598 46259.1078  0.14%   400  375s
H 1476   910                    46325.859273 46259.3600  0.14%   399  381s
  1478   912 46260.2944   22  580 46325.8593 46260.2944  0.14%   398  387s
  1482   914 46269.5730   12  549 46325.8593 46260.4630  0.14%   397  390s
  1483   915 46260.5541   18  571 46325.8593 46260.5541  0.14%   397  395s
  1487   918 46260.7513   18  569 46325.8593 46260.7513  0.14%   396  401s
  1489   919 46260.7513   16  552 46325.8593 46260.7513  0.14%   395  406s
  1492   921 46260.8015   24  558 46325.8593 46260.8015  0.14%   394  412s
  1493   922 46260.9280   14  536 46325.8593 46260.9280  0.14%   394  417s
  1494   922 46260.9280   18  536 46325.8593 46260.9280  0.14%   394  425s
  1495   926 46263.5917   10  492 46325.8593 46260.9280  0.14%   484  431s
  1497   929 46265.7827   11  500 46325.8593 46263.5971  0.13%   486  436s
  1501   930 46267.6998   12  564 46325.8593 46265.8142  0.13%   491  441s
  1505   931 46269.2776   13  562 46325.8593 46267.7040  0.13%   499  445s
  1513   936 46268.9962   15  567 46325.8593 46268.4795  0.12%   510  454s
  1517   939 46271.1531   16  455 46325.8593 46269.0016  0.12%   517  459s
H 1521   898                    46325.859265 46270.0909  0.12%   523  469s
  1530   937 46274.2620   17  500 46325.8593 46271.2649  0.12%   535  484s
  1576   952 46275.4136   19  492 46325.8593 46271.4613  0.12%   549  498s
  1614   976 46286.8799   20  529 46325.8593 46272.4743  0.12%   568  514s
  1655  1017 46273.3852   21  568 46325.8593 46273.2079  0.11%   580  538s
  1719  1053     cutoff   23      46325.8593 46273.8191  0.11%   600  564s
  1790  1116 46274.5933   21  580 46325.8593 46274.5933  0.11%   619  600s
  1898  1167 46275.0296   23  548 46325.8593 46274.7783  0.11%   643  640s
  2015  1212     cutoff   24      46325.8593 46275.4282  0.11%   657  691s
H 2063  1150                    46325.859215 46275.7493  0.11%   669  691s
  2131  1244 46294.7393   18  448 46325.8592 46276.6276  0.11%   687  756s
H 2190  1181                    46325.859206 46276.6403  0.11%   693  756s
  2284  1250 46298.1909   17  532 46325.8592 46277.4630  0.10%   719  834s
H 2361  1183                    46325.859182 46277.5686  0.10%   752  834s
  2442  1291 46278.0391   19  543 46325.8592 46277.9477  0.10%   780  914s
H 2487  1236                    46325.859097 46277.9477  0.10%   789  914s
  2642  1387     cutoff   17      46325.8591 46278.6764  0.10%   836 1005s
H 2717  1325                    46325.858995 46278.8148  0.10%   847 1005s
  2898  1506 46314.0824   27  438 46325.8590 46279.7015  0.10%   875 1112s
H 2970  1447                    46325.858962 46279.7529  0.10%   886 1112s
  3218  1578 46281.1102   26  539 46325.8590 46280.8067  0.10%   915 1221s
  3502  1728 46284.0197   34  466 46325.8590 46281.8305  0.10%   964 1334s
  3781  1941     cutoff   26      46325.8590 46283.0811  0.09%  1003 1449s
  4091  2207     cutoff   22      46325.8590 46283.6827  0.09%  1048 1566s
H 4092  2207                    46325.858956 46283.6827  0.09%  1048 1566s
  4451  2435 46295.3227   31  476 46325.8590 46284.5977  0.09%  1096 1687s
  4778  2711 46302.3946   32  514 46325.8590 46285.2457  0.09%  1135 1827s
H 5062  2711                    46325.858935 46285.2800  0.09%  1162 1828s
  5191  3072 46297.9209   28  554 46325.8589 46285.8805  0.09%  1165 1969s
H 5433  3072                    46325.858923 46285.8912  0.09%  1174 1969s
  5499  3072 46286.5081   29  493 46325.8589 46285.8920  0.09%  1173 1970s
  5684  3301 46299.2461   27  526 46325.8589 46286.5734  0.08%  1181 2102s
  6023  3598 46291.9261   26  550 46325.8589 46287.2734  0.08%  1212 2235s
  6454  4016 46298.6297   38  448 46325.8589 46287.9251  0.08%  1237 2352s
H 6724  4016                    46325.858908 46287.9355  0.08%  1232 2352s
H 6892  4016                    46325.858902 46287.9498  0.08%  1238 2352s
  7024  4420 46289.1203   31  486 46325.8589 46288.4207  0.08%  1240 2472s
  7565  4758 46301.8814   22  537 46325.8589 46288.9335  0.08%  1249 2611s
H 8042  5181                    46325.858866 46289.2099  0.08%  1254 2771s
H 8669  5673                    46325.858858 46289.7616  0.08%  1253 2932s
H 9201  5673                    46325.858848 46289.7827  0.08%  1247 2932s
  9322  6137 46315.9030   29  472 46325.8588 46290.1932  0.08%  1254 3111s
  9973  6600 46292.0057   39  408 46325.8588 46290.7082  0.08%  1255 3287s
 10605  7018 46309.1333   28  446 46325.8588 46290.9329  0.08%  1241 3469s
H10738  7018                    46325.858840 46290.9329  0.08%  1246 3469s
 11231  7553 46293.7213   51  372 46325.8588 46291.3545  0.07%  1252 3647s
 11925  8056 46295.4895   27  463 46325.8588 46291.7021  0.07%  1251 3816s
 12605  8393 46307.5980   50  436 46325.8588 46292.0352  0.07%  1244 3977s
 13073  8853     cutoff   28      46325.8588 46292.2037  0.07%  1250 4152s
 13712  9431 46295.3820   21  576 46325.8588 46292.5288  0.07%  1251 4328s
 14436  9924 46294.9039   50  359 46325.8588 46292.8079  0.07%  1242 4503s
 15079 10427 46294.1207   52  384 46325.8588 46293.0096  0.07%  1243 4665s
H15687 10745                    46325.858491 46293.1855  0.07%  1240 4831s
 16157 11253 46295.2734   34  488 46325.8585 46293.3793  0.07%  1242 4990s
H16791 11809                    46325.858380 46293.5257  0.07%  1237 5155s
 17453 12295     cutoff   34      46325.8584 46293.7137  0.07%  1236 5321s
 18065 12878 46301.5378   38  463 46325.8584 46293.9311  0.07%  1240 5483s
 18819 13450 46294.7760   42  471 46325.8584 46294.1304  0.07%  1234 5646s


Hello, Vida. Usually you add early stopping by gap %, because most tasks are so complex that they can't reach true optimal solution. In my experience gap bound of 1% is enough. However if you can reach better solution in reasonable time you can set gap lower, in your case "0.1%" or less. This is depending only on tolerance of how long you can wait. Use following lines: model.Params.MIPGap = 0.15(# 0.15%) and
model.Params.TimeLimit = 600 (# 10 minutes) and model.optimize()

This is depending only on your tolerance to wait longer for a better solution (additional X minutes of solver will improve optimal gap by Y%).

NP. tag me if you'll have more questions. Cheers.
